# Is that possible to remove the word "nginx" from default 404 page footer without recompiling?

Tags: nginx

I knew I could remove the nginx version by using `server_tokens off;`.

I knew I could modify the nginx header by using `more_set_headers 'Server: myserver';`

I knew I could setup custom 404 page by using `error_page 404 /error/404.html`.

But what if I don't want to use custom 404 page, I just want to use the default 404 page but removing the "nginx" word in the footer? Is that doable?

I am using `nginx-extras` package in debian.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Only by patching and recompiling the sources. Should also be pretty easy.